# How to implement the bowling game kata in C# but with no if or for or any iterative structure

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and i started do to a simple bowling game provided by the BowlingGameKata, it is with the unit test, down below is the code i have at the moment.

Here is the main console application problem:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Game
    {
        public int[] rolls = new int[25];
        private int _current;
        public int CalculateScore()
        {
            int score = 0;
            int i = 0;
            for(int frame = 0; frame < 10; frame++)
            {
                int consecutiveTwoScore = rolls[i] + rolls[i + 1];
                
                if (rolls[i] == 10) //strike
                {
                    score +=consecutiveTwoScore + rolls[i + 2];
                    i += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    //spare
                    if (consecutiveTwoScore == 10)
                    {
                        score += consecutiveTwoScore + rolls[i + 2];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        score += consecutiveTwoScore;

                    }

                    i += 2;
                }
            }

            return score;

        }

        public void Roll(int pins)
        {
            rolls[_current++] = pins;

        }
        
        static void Main()
        {
        }
    }
    

}
```

And here are the tests that need to pass. At the moment everything is working just fine.

```
using ConsoleApp1;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace TestConsolApp
{
    
    public class BowlingScoreTestSuite
    {
      //  public static Game _bowlingGame;
        
        
           

           [Test]
        public void GutterGame()
        {   
            Game bowlingGame= new Game();
            //Arrange
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                bowlingGame.Roll(0);
            }

            //Act+Assert.
            Assert.AreEqual(0,bowlingGame.CalculateScore());
        }

        [Test]
        public void AllOnesGames()
        {
            Game bowlingGame= new Game();
  
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                bowlingGame.Roll(1);
            }

            Assert.AreEqual(20,bowlingGame.CalculateScore());
        }
            
        public void OneSpareGame()
        {
            Game bowlingGame= new Game();
            //Arrange
            bowlingGame.Roll(3);
            bowlingGame.Roll(7);
            bowlingGame.Roll(1);
            for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
            {
                bowlingGame.Roll(1);
            }
            Assert.AreEqual(12,bowlingGame.CalculateScore());
        }
        
            
        [Test]
        public void OneStrikeGame()
        {
            Game bowlingGame= new Game();
            //Arrange
            bowlingGame.Roll(3);
            bowlingGame.Roll(7);
            bowlingGame.Roll(1);
            for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
            {
                bowlingGame.Roll(0);
            }
          //  RollMany(16, 0);
                
            Assert.AreEqual(12,bowlingGame.CalculateScore());
        }

        [Test]
        public void PerfectGame()
        {
            Game bowlingGame= new Game();
            //Arrange
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
                bowlingGame.Roll(10);
            }
            //RollMany(12, 0);
                
            Assert.AreEqual(300,bowlingGame.CalculateScore());
        }

    }
    
}
```

The problem that i have is that i need to change in the consoleApp1 the code such that there are no if's no fors and any other iterative structure. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: *Why* do you need no if/else statements? They're perfectly fine to use. The only reason I could think of for not wanting to use them is if you're being tested to write some code without them. In that case, asking for help kind of defeats the purpose of the test...

Comment: @ObsidianAge it's a challenge i was given, the thing is only in the console app i can not use if for etc. I', supposed to make more methods and implement them so the test will also work.

Comment: Test OneSpareGame seems wrong to me (the test): to get 12 as expected, you should add 17 gutter for the last 17 rolls (and not 17 1 pin score). Am I missing something?